# How do you reparent a Windows Store Metro app to a different dev account?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have an app that is already in the store, but I want to transfer ownership of that app to a different developer account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an automated way to do this, but I believe it can be done if you contact Microsoft Support to request a transfer.

Go to http://aka.ms/storesupport and log in as the current owner account, click [select your type of problem here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=390481), and set the Problem type to "Store Registration and your account". That should connect you with the right people.